# Eclipse Debug Suspended at My Breakpoint and the line is not highlighted

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I made two Break points in a java file in Eclipse, when I run the application the Debugger says that it is suspended at the exact line of the break point, but the line doesn't get selected and I can't step to the next line or continue the debugging process, I only got the resume option and when I click it the same happens with the next break point.

**UPDATE**: When I put breakpoints somewhere else other than that file it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like you have two instances of your program running in debug mode.

Comment: no, actually it is one.

Comment: What line is your breakpoint on? Does it contain code, or is it a breakpoint on a class attribute (also called watchpoint)? What does it look like (symbol) in the "Breakpoints" window (ALT+SHIFT+Q, B)?

Answer (score 1):

Double click the supended method (the one with the pause icon) in the debug view. This will bring you to the breakpoint and step over etc. should work.

Comment: suspend icon is inactive.

Comment: @OdO You are looking at the wrong place. Please check the debug view (not perspective) carefully.